# Weird 404 error in application.log and getting YII to ignore them?

Tags: yii, bots

Something is access my site using this URL:

```
/(Yvax:%20uggc:/jjj.tbbtyr-nanylgvpf.pbz/hepuva.wf)uggc:/jjj.tbbtyr-nanylgvpf.pbz/hepuva.wf
```

So I get error:

```
[error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException'
```

1. Is it something to worry about?
2. How can I stop YII from reporting on this specific error and other similar 404 errors that are unwanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just a scanner script. We get hit by these all the time. Review security, but as long as that checks out you should be fine.